# (1002) - No available client connector supports the required protocol: 'HTTPS'

Tags: android, https, client, restlet

I'm trying to set up a HTTPS client on Android using Restlet but I get this error:

> Internal Connector Error (1002) - No available client connector
>   supports the required protocol: 'HTTPS'. Please add the JAR of a
>   matching connector to your classpath. Then, register this connector
>   helper manually.

Many sources say you just need to add the jars for ssl and dependencies, so I've added the following jars:

- org.restlet
- org.restlet.ext.ssl

  - org.jsslutils
- org.restlet.ext.httpclient

  - org.apache.commons.codec_1.5
  - org.apache.commons.logging_1.1
  - org.apache.httpclient_4.1
  - org.apache.httpcore_4.1
  - org.apache.httpmime_4.1
  - org.apache.james.mime4j_0.6
  - net.jcip.annotations_1.0

Restlet's [docs](http://restlet.org/learn/1.0/connectors) say you need to add an external "connector" for HTTPS.
According to it, the options for a HTTPS CLIENT are:

1. Apache HTTP Client
2. Net (which comes with the JDK)

I'm assuming I have both on (org.apache.httpclient_4.1 and JDK).

The error message mentions "register the connector helper manually" but I couldn't figure out how to do it. The docs mention parameters for the connectors. Some links there are broken, others go to javadocs with no extra text. [This one](http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/2.1/jse/engine/org/restlet/engine/connector/BaseHelper.html) lists some parameters, but all seemingly optional settings and nothing about setting an alternative connector. Some sources on the web had code snippets setting stuff by "System.setProperty". I copy-pasted some and tried with no success.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: We gave up using Restlet altogether. Used only Apache's httpclient as far as I can remember.

Comment: Please see my answer below. This issue should be fully solved now in version 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fully solved in Restlet version 2.2 where the internal HTTP/HTTPS connector is now based on HttpURLConnection, there requiring NO additional dependencies. It is lightweigth and doesn't need to use the Apache HTTP Client API. This works especially well for the Android edition.